# how to get all entries of today date?

Tags: java, android, sql

hi i m fetching the all entries of today date i write the query for that but i did not get the correct entries. please solve my issue .below i write my code.thank you.

```
public ArrayList<groups> fetchByTodayDate(){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.DATETIME + "<=date('now')";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    ArrayList<groups> all = new ArrayList<groups>();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            groups data = new groups();
            smsdata.setMsgtext(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TEXTMSG)));
            smsdata.setSmsId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID)));

            all.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return all;
}
```

Comment: Only today's entries or less than today's entries?

Comment: only today's entry

Comment: Try below answer..

Comment: @DrKaoliN after changing the query it gives the records of today date and future date also ,But i want only today records.

Answer (score 0):

("SELECT  * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE " + KEY_DATE + "='" + date + "'", null);

Comment: hi i tried this one but i did not get the entries. before i mentioned query in my question String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE "+ DatabaseHelper.DATETIME+"<=date('now')";  i get the entries from database but it did not give correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for **today's** entries:-

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " WHERE date(datetime("+ DatabaseHelper.DATETIME+"/1000, 'unixepoch','localtime'))=date('now')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ArrayList<groups> fetchByTodayDate()
{
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
ArrayList<groups> all = new ArrayList<>();

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

cursor.moveToFirst ();

while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
all.add(new groups (
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TEXTMSG)),
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID))
));

cursor.moveToNext ();
}

cursor.close();
db.close();

return all;
}
```